# How to extract linear models regression coefficients when using M5 with the train function of the caret package?

Tags: r, regression, weka, r-caret

I have built a M5 [regression](/questions/tagged/regression) model tree using the train function of the `caret` package. I am trying to extract the `linear model coefficients` for each model of the tree.

The final model is called `m5tune`. I tried to look into `m5tune$finalModel` but I did not find it. The `coeff()` function does not seem to work either...

Comment: Dear [Ibo34](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9851830/lbo34), welcome to SO. Please take a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), to modify your question, with a smaller sample taken from your data (check?dput()). Posting images of your data or no data makes it difficult to impossible for us to help you!

Comment: I had a look in `finalModel` and could not find the regression coefficients readily available. The object that seems to hold them is `finalModel$classifier` but this is only a handle (`jobref`) for a java object...

Comment: What I am trying to do is to plot the linear model coefficients for each node of the tree. finalModel displays the coefficients on the screen, but I did not find a way to extract them in a data table for instance to plot them.